# Is a comma needed after stares?

Tags: commas

> "Bob asks if Sam remembers his cousin's favourite hobby. Sam stares confused."

Is a comma needed after stares?

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: Some creative writing of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma, so that “confused” modifies Sam and not “stares.” Otherwise you could say, without a comma, Sam stares confusedly.